# Laravel Migration:refresh authetication Problem

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am building a blog by Laravel. I use `migration:refresh` to adjust the name of one of my table.

After that my login is not working and keep saying

> "These credentials do not match our records"

though the login information is correct. Here is my seeds

```
App\User::create([
        'name'=> 'name',
        'email'=>'name@gmail.com',
        'password'=>bcrypt('laravel')
]);
```

I am new in laravel. Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the the `bcrypt()` to `Hash::make()`

```
use Hash;

App\User::create([
        'name'=> 'name',
        'email'=>'name@gmail.com',
        'password'=> Hash::make('laravel') 
]);
```

And run

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Comment: Thanks @Jesus. Its working now.But whats the problem with bcrypt()?

Comment: You can see more details here explaining the hash and bcrypt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899905/bcrypt-vs-hash-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Try this command it works for me

```
php artisan migrate:fresh

php artisan migrate
```